# Order column by certain criteria in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I need to be able to order my output data in a proper way using `MySQL`.
I'm using `ORDER BY` so far and everything was working correctly until now.

Let's say I have something like this:
Table `VEHICLES`:

```
ID | Name | MainGroup | SubGroup 
1  |  A   |   Vehicle |   Truck
2  |  B   |   Vehicle |   Car
3  |  C   |   Vehicle |   Car
4  |  D   |   Vehicle |   Truck
5  |  E   |   Vehicle |   Truck
6  |  F   |   Vehicle |   Motorbike
```

I was using this:

```
SELECT * FROM Vehicles WHERE MainGroup=Vehicle ORDER BY Subgroup;
```

When I get selections they are not sorted in a way that I want, because now I want to be able to determine the way of the selected ones. Let's say that I want an output like this `Car, Truck, Motorbike` or some other way around. How to achieve this?
Is this doable using an `order by`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `field()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Vehicles
WHERE MainGroup=Vehicle
ORDER BY field(Subgroup, 'Car', 'Truck', 'Motorbike');
```

Comment: can I have multiple fields in one sql query?

Comment: @user123_456 . . . I think the answer is "yes", but I'm not sure what you mean.  `field()` is just a MySQL function, which is documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field.

Comment: Problem that I get is that I need to apply one more order by for each of those subgroups. For example I have one more column (price) and when I do something like this I get wrong results. `SELECT *
FROM Vehicles
WHERE MainGroup=Vehicle
ORDER BY field(Subgroup, 'Car', 'Truck', 'Motorbike'), Price ASC;`

Comment: @user123_456 . . . That is a different question from the one you asked.  Your query will group first by the subgroup and then by the price.  If that is not what you want, then it is not the right query to use.

Comment: you can check out my linked questions as well