# Order column by certain multiple criteria in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

This question was partly answered that's why I need to create another question in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325200/order-column-by-certain-criteria-in-mysql).
I'm sure that some other people would search for something similar.

If I have table like this:

Table `VEHICLES`:

```
ID | Name | MainGroup | SubGroup   |  Price
1  |  A   |   Vehicle |   Truck    |   1399
2  |  B   |   Vehicle |   Car      |   200
3  |  C   |   Vehicle |   Car      |   1400
4  |  D   |   Vehicle |   Truck    |    50
5  |  E   |   Vehicle |   Truck    |    3200
6  |  F   |   Vehicle |   Motorbike|    79
```

If I use this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM Vehicles
WHERE MainGroup=Vehicle
ORDER BY field(Subgroup, 'Car', 'Truck', 'Motorbike');
```

it will only order by `subgroup` and I want to have it ordered by the `price` as well.
I've tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM Vehicles
WHERE MainGroup=Vehicle
ORDER BY field(Subgroup, 'Car', 'Truck', 'Motorbike'), Price ASC;
```

then my data got order by `Price` only.

I want to be able to get something like this:

```
ID | Name | MainGroup | SubGroup   |  Price
2  |  B   |   Vehicle |   Car      |   200
3  |  C   |   Vehicle |   Car      |   1400
4  |  D   |   Vehicle |   Truck    |    50
1  |  A   |   Vehicle |   Truck    |   1399
5  |  E   |   Vehicle |   Truck    |   3200
6  |  F   |   Vehicle |   Motorbike|    79
```

What would be the right way of using order by for this? Or some other MySQL functions?

Comment: The code what you tried should work http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f274ee/1

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of using it:

```
SELECT *
FROM Vehicles
WHERE MainGroup=Vehicle
ORDER BY Price ASC, field(Subgroup, 'Car', 'Truck', 'Motorbike');
```

Comment: I've tried that as well and it's not giving me the right results. Especially when some prices are set on 0 by default. Results are mixed up